# firejail for complete security (for scripts downloaded from Inet)

Tags: linux, debian, security, firejail

I need to run scripts downloaded from the untrusted network.

I want to run such scripts in Firejail.

But `firejail --caps.drop=all ls /home/porton/` shows that it has access to my home directory! It is not what I need.

How to configure Firejail (or another security container) to be able to access only non-secret information (such as OS installation in `/usr/`, `/tmp` (preferably empty), and no home directories)?

Debian Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Your example command:

```
firejail --caps.drop=all ls /home/porton/
```

Creates a sandbox in your /home/porton/ directory according to firejail [documentation](https://firejail.wordpress.com/documentation-2/firefox-guide/). This is an example for how to create a sandbox for firefox but if you look at the [manpage](https://firejail.wordpress.com/features-3/man-firejail/), you can see that your scripts either need a profile created to have the behavior you are asking for or you need to specify the directory that you will use. Here is an example that will create a chroot for the container:

```
firejail --caps.drop=all --chroot=/tmp/test [Path/to/your/script/here]
```

Firejail will take system directories and directories belonging to another application and mount them as read-only and they cannot be modified by the application. If you want to test this do not forget to use the --audit flag to test the sandbox. Test all of this on a bash script that you trust, like a script to write to a directory that is outside the sandbox and read from files outside of the sandbox, etc.

Another option is to simply run any untrusted scripts on a VM that is not attached to the network, or other pc not connected to the network. Best of luck and remember to refer to any documentation of programs you are trying to run.

Comment: It does not work: `Error: chroot directory should be owned by root`. But I want to run my software as non-root

Comment: I would then suggest you run your script in private mode:  `firejail --private [program --arguments]`. That should hide all files in your home directory.